# Chaining jquery keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a drop down like functionality where a div is shown once somebody starts typing in the input box. I am able to attach mouse click event on the individual elements to select them. But I am not able to select them via pressing enter.

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="input" name="example" id="example" placeholder="example..." autocomplete="off" list="examplelist" />

<div class="autofill">
    <ul class="autocomplete">
        <li class="autocomplete-list">John Doe (San Jose, CA)</li>
        <li class="autocomplete-list">Jane Doe (San Francisco, CA)</li>
        <li class="autocomplete-list">John Jane (San Carlos, CA)</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $listItems = $('li.autocomplete-list'),
    $div = $('div.autofill'),
    $input = $('#example');

$div.hide();

$('input#example').on('keydown', function (e) {
    var key = e.keyCode,
        $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
        $current;

    $div.show();

    if (key != 40 && key != 38) return;

    $listItems.removeClass('selected');

    if (key == 40) { // Down key
        if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
            $current = $listItems.eq(0);
        } else {
            $current = $selected.next();
        }
    } else if (key == 38) { // Up key
        if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
            $current = $listItems.last();
        } else {
            $current = $selected.prev();
        }
    }

    $current.addClass('selected');

    // When I press enter after selecting the li element
    // Does not work :(
    $current.on('keypress keydown keyup', 'li', function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            var value = $(this).text().split('(')[0].trim();
            $input.val(value) ;
            $div.hide();
        }
    });
});


// If somebody clicks on the li item
$('li.autocomplete-list').on('click', function (e) {
    var value = $(this).text().split('(')[0].trim();
    $input.val(value);
    $div.hide();
});

// change color on hover
$('li.autocomplete-list').hover(
    function(){ $(this).addClass('hover') },
    function(){ $(this).removeClass('hover') }
);

// When I press enter after selecting the li element
// Does not work :( 

$('li.autocomplete-list').on('keypress keydown keyup', 'li', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var value = $(this).text().split('(')[0].trim();
        $input.val(value) ;
        $div.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

How can I select a particular li element and then take its value when press enter? Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q1vtwtdp/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<li>` element doesn't have focus, even though it's selected visually. The text input still has focus.

You need to check for the enter key on the text `<input>`. Not on the `<li>`

```
$('input#example').on('keydown', function (e) {
    //...
    var key = e.keyCode
    if (key == 40) { // Down key
        //...
    } else if (key == 38) { // Up key
        //...
    } else if (key == 13) { // Enter key
        //... make sure $current is not null
    }
 //...
 }
```

Also be careful of this statement

```
 if (key != 40 && key != 38) return;
```

Which will return from the event handler when the enter key is pressed.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q1vtwtdp/4/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, i have tried that already. If you check for $current and key == 13, then it still does not solve my purpose because I dont get the value of selected element. Am I missing there something ?

Comment: I figured out my issue. Your pointer was correct for ignoring the return statement on key 38 and 40 . Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/q1vtwtdp/17/

Answer (score 0):

Jordan P is correct, the handling of the list should all happen within the keydown handler function of the input.

```
$('input#example').on('keydown', function (e) {

    var key = e.keyCode,
        $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
        $current;

    $div.show();        

    $listItems.removeClass('selected');

    if (key == 40) { // Down key
        if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
            $current = $listItems.eq(0);
        } else {
            $current = $selected.next();
        }
    }

    if (key == 38) { // Up key
        if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
            $current = $listItems.last();
        } else {
            $current = $selected.prev();
        }
    }

    if (key == 13) {
        var value = $('.autocomplete-list').html().split('(')[0].trim();
        $input.val(value);
        $div.hide();
        $current = $selected
    }


    $current.addClass('selected');

});
```

So you don't need:

```
$('li.autocomplete-list').on('keypress keydown keyup', 'li', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var value = $(this).text().split('(')[0].trim();
        $input.val(value) ;
        $div.hide();
    }
  });
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1vtwtdp/41/)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes I did the same thing and posted my answer in new jsfiddle link in comments to Jordan's answer: jsfiddle.net/q1vtwtdp/17